# Are there any plans to turn any Neal Stephenson novels into film/TV?

Tags: neal-stephenson

Are there any plans afoot to adapt any of the works by Neal Stephenson into film or television?

Has Neal Stephenson sold any of the rights to anyone?

Answer (score 10):

When film and television rights for books are sold, they often just float around for a long time in eternal pre-production. However, for stuff that is will actually happen, there is some good news.

[Amazon is making a Snow Crash TV series](http://deadline.com/2017/09/ringworld-lazarus-snow-crash-amazon-genre-drama-series-push-1202179073/). Here's the details from the linked article:

> Snow Crash, a co-production with Paramount TV, is a one-hour science
>   fiction drama based on Stephenson’s novel, which is set in futuristic
>   America. In reality, Hiro Protagonist delivers pizza for Uncle Enzo’s
>   CosoNostra Pizza Inc., but in the Metaverse he’s a warrior prince.
>   Plunging headlong into the enigma of a new computer virus that’s
>   striking down hackers everywhere, he races along the neon-lit streets
>   on a search-and-destroy mission for the shadowy virtual villain.
>
> Snow Crash is executive produced by Joe Cornish (Ant-Man) and Kennedy
>   Marshall Company’s Frank Marshall (Back to the Future, Raiders of the
>   Lost Ark).

Comment: That description makes me fear it'll turn into an episodic PI drama rather than the coherent arc story it should be.  Ah, TV.

Answer (score 3):

Ron Howard is developing Seveneves into a movie.  There hasn't been any news on it in a couple years so the project may have stalled.  [Variety](https://variety.com/2016/film/news/ron-howard-sevenes-skydance-1201791761/) reported on it in 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Neal Stephenson states in the video linked below that after Snowcrash, he feels that his novels are simply too long to adapt into a movie, and that a short story is probably the best fit for translation to a movie.

He adds in this [exposition on his novels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozcki71QHYI) that the miniseries is probably the best fit, and he simply hasn't been approached to do this.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the YouTube video dates back to September 2011; the articles linked in the other answers are more recent.